# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'face' even after installed opencv-contrib-python

Tags: python, django, opencv, pip

I got an error while running django server. I installed opencv-python and opencv-contrib-python through pip. Still getting the same error. Any suggestions?

```
Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/auxouser/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/auxouser/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 124, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/auxouser/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 359, in check include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/auxouser/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 346, in _run_checks return checks.run_checks(**kwargs) 
  File "/home/auxouser/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/auxouser/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/auxouser/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver return check_method()
  File "/home/auxouser/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 254, in check for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/home/auxouser/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/auxouser/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 405, in url_patterns patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/auxouser/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__ res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/auxouser/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 398, in urlconf_module return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/auxouser/Auxo/projects/training-ds/Day-9/Face_Recognition/Face_Recognition/urls.py", line 3, in 
    from MyAPP import views
  File "/home/auxouser/Auxo/projects/training-ds/Day-9/Face_Recognition/MyAPP/views.py", line 12, in 
    recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'face'
```

Comment: Well apparently somewhere you perform a `.face` call, and `.face` is indeed not a direct attribute. Can you share the traceback?

Comment: Can you post more details about your error, the full traceback?

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question so we can help.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a module named `cv.py` (or `cv2.py` in this case) in your project - that means `import cv2` is importing your own module, not opencv, and `cv2.face` will fail.

Delete your .py file and the .pyc that was generated, and the import should work again.